# jQuery Desktop / Mobile tab content switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I was working on a tabber plugin that changes its tab contents on window resize, e.g. I have some price tables that correspond to different tabs. The tabs content consist of price tables in image format which change layout on lower resolution.

Everything was working fine until at one point for no obvious reason for me, the second part of the plugin stopped working.

---

### ***The problem is present ONLY in [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/)***

---

Here is some sample code related to the fact that the resize capture function works, but the code inside the else conditional doesn't:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    console.log($(window).width());
    resizeCheck();
});
```

The problem is with the mobile version, my else statement which contains the conditionals for the new layout (***the select list with its options that link to the tabs***) and type of the tabs is not responding. What am I supposed to do for it in order to start working? What am I doing wrong?

---

### And here is a full ***[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kbv8vwnh/14/)***

---

Comment: I think for me (Edge on Windows 10) it is working as you intended - the style changes as the window increases beyone 1179 pixels wide and back again when the width drops below that value.   Perhaps you could say exactly what you do expect and in what way and where it is not working.

Comment: Yes Mr Smith (had to write it) , but my problem lies within below 1179px, not above it. The mobile condition is not working.

Comment: For me it switched between the two layouts without a problem.  Going above 1179 it switched and going below 1179 it switched back again without a problem. - could you say what browser you are using.

Comment: Firefox Developer Edition, that is strange because I really depended on that browser to not let me down. Oh well. I guess I won't be looking for a fix since I doubt that any normal users would download this browser, what will you advise me to do?

Comment: I can't comment on your version of Firefox, although I'm surprised - usually Firefox is rock solid on these kind of issues.  I tested on Chrome50, Firefox46, Edge25 (EdgeHTML13) and it was fine on all of them.  I'm afraid as it is not going wrong for me it is hard to know what your problem actually is, sorry.